# in Random.java, isn't x&((1L<<48)-1)==x?

Tags: java, random, bitwise-and

See `int next(int bits)` from http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html.  It contains the line

```
seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
```

The number `(1L<<48)-1` is `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`.  Does and'ing it with a number do anything?  Is this a quirk with signed longs?  Is this old outdated code?

Comment: How did you get 64 ones as the answer? Isn't it 48 ones?

Comment: It masks the number to 48 bits.

Comment: facepalm.  glossed over 48.  thanks!

Comment: And by the way, if you want random numbers across the entire 64-bit range of a `long` (without the 48-bit limitation seen in your Question), use the [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) class instead of [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html). See [OpenJDK source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.java).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't 64 ones:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

It's 48 ones:

```
0000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

ANDing with this number clears the leftmost 16 bits.